# WordPress query - Order by meta-field value

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I have a post with three meta-fields.

```
add_post_meta($my_post, 'times', $times);
```

And i would like to query this category and sort the posts by the meta field value of one of them.
The args i use right now are:

```
  $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => 'players',
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'times',
        'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'times',
           'value' => 0,
           'compare' => '>=',
       ),
        'posts_per_page'=> '8'
        )
        );
```

Where times is the name of the metafield.The above code isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

You have `'posts_per_page'=> '8'` inside your `meta_query` argument.

Change your code into the following:

```
$args=array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'category_name' => 'players',
    'order' => 'DESC', 
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => 'times',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'times',
            'value' => 0,
            'compare' => '>=',
        )
    ),
    'posts_per_page'=> '8'
);
```

Comment: Still didn't work...i think that the problem is in the meta query

Comment: Removing code from 'orderby' to 'posts_per_page' and adding 'get_post_meta' => array( $id, 'times' ) instead returned a result.

Comment: The problem is that i need them ordered

Comment: solved with <pre>
 $args=array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => 'players',
        'order' => 'DESC', 
        'meta_key' => 'times',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        
        );
</pre>