# Sort by custom meta_key in WordPress get_posts(), and include posts that do not have the meta_key

Tags: wordpress

I have set on my WordPress post custom meta called "my_sort" which have a numeric values like 1, 2, 3, 4..... See below image:

[image]

I want to sort in ascending order by this meta "my_sort". This is the below code I am applying:

```
<?php 
    $catPost = get_posts(array('category' => get_cat_ID($categories[0]->name), 'meta_key' => 'my_sort', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'ASC', 'numberposts' => 100)); //change this
  ?>
```

The problem with this code is that it is working but has one problem which I need to be fixed.

It is leaving all the other posts which do not have "my_sort" meta in them. I want to include those posts also. I want:

1. First the posts that have "my_sort" must come in ascending order.
2. Then the post that do not have "my_sort" meta should come.

**Update**

When I try the below query.

```
$catPost = get_posts( 
        array (
            'category' => get_cat_ID($categories[0]->name), 
            'numberposts' => 100, 
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
            'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
            'order' => 'ASC', 
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                   'key'=>'my_sort',
                   'compare' => 'EXISTS'         
                ),
                array(
                    'key'=>'my_sort',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'         
                )
            ),
        )
      );
```

I do not get proper result. See the image which shows the result.

Here:

Record1 : does not have "my_sort" meta.

Record2 : does have "my_sort" and it's value is 2.

Record3 : does not have "my_sort" meta.

Record4 : does have "my_sort" meta and it's value is 4.

The result in this case should be like this:

**Record2 then Record4 then Record1 then Record4** but clearly this is not the case.

What is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress query - Order by meta-field value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361327/wordpress-query-order-by-meta-field-value)

Comment: @FluffyKitten no i am not using meta_query.

Comment: You need to if you want to sort by meta key!

Comment: @FluffyKitten there is no compare in my case. Just ascending order. Can you provide me the answer in the box so that I can check.

Comment: Can you change it from `get_posts` to use `WP_Query` i.e. `$myquery = WP_Query( array ( ... );` with all the same args except replace `numberposts` with `posts_per_page`. When you have that working, can you then add this and let us know what it prints out:  `echo $myquery->request;`

Comment: When using `WP_Query` then some other posts (i.e. post not of the respective category) shows up. WP_Query fails. The response text is - `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts.ID FROM `

Comment: `wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts LEFT JOIN wp_cyq2wqaj4a_postmeta ON ( wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts.ID = wp_cyq2wqaj4a_postmeta.post_id ) LEFT JOIN wp_cyq2wqaj4a_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = 'my_sort' ) WHERE 1=1 AND ( ( wp_cyq2wqaj4a_postmeta.meta_key = 'my_sort' OR mt1.post_id IS NULL ) ) AND wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts.post_type = 'post' AND (wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_cyq2wqaj4a_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_cyq2wqaj4a_postmeta.meta_value+0 ASC LIMIT 0, 100`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort by a meta key that might not have any values, you need to use a `meta_query` that combines the results of a search for posts *with* the key and a search for posts *without* the key.

This isn't tested, but the main logic is there:

```
$catPost = get_posts( 
    array (
        'category' => get_cat_ID($categories[0]->name), 
        'numberposts' => 100, 
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
        'meta_type' => 'NUMERIC',
        'order' => 'ASC', 
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
               'key'=>'my_sort',
               'compare' => 'EXISTS'         
            ),
            array(
                'key'=>'my_sort',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'         
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: The query works quite well. It is giving all records but sort order is not working properly. This is not returning records in the way I needed 1. First the posts that have "my_sort" must come in ascending order. 2. Then the post that do not have "my_sort" meta should come.

Comment: @yogihosting Try adding `’meta_key’ => ‘my_sort’,` to the array outside the `meta_query` (e.g. after `'numberposts’ => 100,` ). Also, what order are they being returned in? If we know that, it would help us fix the order.

Comment: it's not working. I just check it when i put 'meta_key' => 'my_sort' after 'numberposts' => 100 and outside the 'meta_query' then the records that don't have 'my_sort' does not show up.

Comment: When you were using it before that line, what order were they showing then? Also, what type is my_sort when it is created? If it’s just a general text field, then add the meta_type like in my updated answer above. And let me know what order they appear with this *and* without it if it does t work!

Comment: meta_type is Numeric. I have tested it by applying it on the code but no use. What I need is posts not having 'my_sort' meta should come after posts that have 'my_sort'.

Comment: @yogihosting Yes, I understand what you need, I;m asking what are you getting right now? As I said, I can't test this because I don't have your CPTs etc set up, so you need to give me the feedback I can use to help!

Comment: It's not working. I have added (just now) more details in my Question with image that explains what I am getting and what I need to get. Please have a look. Thank you.